# Why status bar color is slightly dark from appbar color in flutter-android?

Tags: android, flutter

What i had tried,

```
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-flutter/
```

I tried every solution from above blog, but i cant find proper solution.

In this below image status bar is slightly dark blue
I want to same color as appbar color

[Statusbar Color](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/951de21ef616fe9e992c6e25ee46801645dd0db0/43881/images/flutter-statusbar-ad-light-dark.png)

Comment: I believe it is because on Android the navigation bar is overlaid on top of the AppBar with some transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default the Android navigation bar sits on top of the flutter app AppBar and has some transparency. You are on the right track with editing the status bar. By default it looks something like this:
[image]

You can edit the status bar color manually by adding a `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` to the `build` function of the root widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
    ));
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

You will need to import `services.dart` as well:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

But then your status bar/app bar should look like this:
[image]

There are other properties you can play with here, check out the API documentation for the [SystemUiOverlayStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html) class